Does 綴{つづ}り also imply the 漢字 used to write a word?
"お名前の綴りを教えてください。" Would this imply one is asking for just the ひらがな spelling for a person's name, or the 漢字, or both (e.g. whatever's the most common way to spell it)?

The term 綴り (and スペル) is usually used in the context of English and similar alphabetical languages. If you ask like that, people will likely be puzzled, and some might wonder if you're asking for the romaji spelling. If you want to know the kanji, it's best to say お名前の漢字を教えてください or お名前を漢字で教えてください. Some people don't have kanji in their names, but they won't feel offended and will just say 「ぜんぶ平仮名で "あゆみ" です」 or something similar.

In addition to what @naruto already said above, the hiragana spelling is not usually asked about for anything, since it is a phonemic script (mostly). Generally, the verb 読む is used in cases where the underlying pronunciation is not clear from the kanji spelling. So if you're asking for the "hiragana spelling" of something, in Japanese you are asking for the 読み方 (よみかた).
